# Can we split a binary avro binary and send it using HTTP?

Tags: http, go, split, avro

i don't have a lot of experience with avro, i was using it some weeks ago to send binary data on HTTP 1.1 using golang to an Arduino, so here my schema is going to be more and more big and i want to split that binary into blocks so fo that i need to know :

1. Can we really Split avro binary into blocks and then reassemble that blocks in reception ?
2. Is it a good idea to do many HTTP requests and responses for one binary or i have to start learning mapReduce and Hadoop ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve and I am not familiar with Arduino. But from what I understand, it seems that you trying to do something similar to what kafka does. Would suggest that you read about how kafka work [link](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol)

> schema is going to be more and more big

you mean the actual data that you are sending, not the schema right?

I think the way to go would be sending data over TCP record by record, but again, there is no enough contex of your usecase

Comment: the schema is going to be more complex and the so avro binary can be voluminous, i don't want to send the data record by record , i want to generate only one big binary and then split it